# why execute time is less when I set the useOptimized false

Tags: python, opencv

python: 3.8.0
openCV: 4.2.0
environment: pyCharm

When I setUseOptimized false, the execute time is less than when it's true. Why? It should be slower. What happened?
This is my code and output.

```
import cv2

print(cv2.useOptimized())

img = cv2.imread('images/ship.bmp')

e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
res = cv2.medianBlur(img, 49)
e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
print((e2 - e1) / cv2.getTickFrequency())

cv2.setUseOptimized(False)
print(cv2.useOptimized())
e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
res = cv2.medianBlur(img, 49)
e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
print((e2 - e1) / cv2.getTickFrequency())
```

```
True
0.000351
False
0.0002813
```

Comment: when I change `res = cv2.mediaBlur(img, 49)` into `for i in range(5, 49, 2): 
res = cv2.mediaBlur(img, i)` , the output seems to be normal.
`True
0.0064761
False
0.0066718`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the openCV docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#setuseoptimized) there are a few reasons that you could be observing such a result

1. Your platform doesn't support any optimisation code (such as SSE, AVX)
2. The operation you're performing doesn't include optimisation code.
3. The operation you're performing does not expose the benefit of optimisation. I.e. performing a single medianBlur is a relatively simple task that doesn't consume too many resources.
4. You haven't repeated the testing enough to get a reliable result.
5. The system you're executing the script on is running other processes that are skewing the results.

On my machine, I ran the following:

```
import cv2
from enum import Enum


class CPUFeatures(Enum):
    CPU_MMX = 1
    CPU_SSE = 2
    CPU_SSE2 = 3
    CPU_SSE3 = 4
    CPU_SSSE3 = 5
    CPU_SSE4_1 = 6
    CPU_SSE4_2 = 7
    CPU_POPCNT = 8
    CPU_FP16 = 9
    CPU_AVX = 10
    CPU_AVX2 = 11
    CPU_FMA3 = 12
    CPU_AVX_512F = 13
    CPU_AVX_512BW = 14
    CPU_AVX_512CD = 15
    CPU_AVX_512DQ = 16
    CPU_AVX_512ER = 17
    CPU_AVX_512IFMA512 = 18
    CPU_AVX_512IFMA = 18
    CPU_AVX_512PF = 19
    CPU_AVX_512VBMI = 20
    CPU_AVX_512VL = 21
    CPU_AVX_512VBMI2 = 22
    CPU_AVX_512VNNI = 23
    CPU_AVX_512BITALG = 24
    CPU_AVX_512VPOPCNTDQ = 25
    CPU_AVX_5124VNNIW = 26
    CPU_AVX_5124FMAPS = 27
    CPU_NEON = 100
    CPU_MSA = 150
    CPU_VSX = 200
    CPU_VSX3 = 201
    CPU_AVX512_SKX = 256
    CPU_AVX512_COMMON = 257
    CPU_AVX512_KNL = 258
    CPU_AVX512_KNM = 259
    CPU_AVX512_CNL = 260
    CPU_AVX512_CLX = 261
    CPU_AVX512_ICL = 262
    CPU_MAX_FEATURE = 512


def run_optimised(img, repeat):
    cv2.setUseOptimized(True)
    start = cv2.getTickCount()
    for i in range(repeat):
        cv2.medianBlur(img, 49)
    # Get performance count
    time = (cv2.getTickCount() - start) / cv2.getTickFrequency()
    return time


def run_non_optimised(img, repeat):
    cv2.setUseOptimized(False)
    start = cv2.getTickCount()
    for i in range(repeat):
        cv2.medianBlur(img, 49)
    # Get performance count
    time = (cv2.getTickCount() - start) / cv2.getTickFrequency()
    return time


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Supported CPU features")
    for cpu_feature in CPUFeatures:
        supported = cv2.checkHardwareSupport(int(cpu_feature.value))
        print("{} is {} supported".format(cpu_feature, "" if supported else "not"))

    print("\nRunning tests\n")
    img = cv2.imread('C:/tiger.jpg')

    repeats = 3
    iterations = 100
    total_optimised = 0
    total_non_optimised = 0
    for i in range(repeats):
        print("Test # {}".format(i))
        optimised = run_optimised(img, iterations)
        non_optimised = run_non_optimised(img, iterations)
        print("Optimised: {}".format(optimised))
        print("Non-optimised: {}".format(non_optimised))
        total_optimised += optimised
        total_non_optimised += non_optimised

    print("Final - optimised: {}".format(optimised))
    print("Final - non-optimised: {}".format(non_optimised))=
```

Which produced the following output:

```
>python test.py
Supported CPU features
CPUFeatures.CPU_MMX is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_SSE is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_SSE2 is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_SSE3 is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_SSSE3 is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_SSE4_1 is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_SSE4_2 is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_POPCNT is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_FP16 is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX2 is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_FMA3 is  supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512F is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512BW is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512CD is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512DQ is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512ER is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512IFMA512 is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512PF is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512VBMI is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512VL is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512VBMI2 is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512VNNI is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512BITALG is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_512VPOPCNTDQ is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_5124VNNIW is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX_5124FMAPS is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_NEON is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_MSA is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_VSX is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_VSX3 is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX512_SKX is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX512_COMMON is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX512_KNL is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX512_KNM is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX512_CNL is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX512_CLX is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_AVX512_ICL is not supported
CPUFeatures.CPU_MAX_FEATURE is not supported

Running tests

Test # 0
Optimised: 2.210887199547867
Non-optimised: 2.659088088298851
Test # 1
Optimised: 2.2174625162069614
Non-optimised: 2.341818393377586
Test # 2
Optimised: 2.235847859572912
Non-optimised: 2.352969891067055
Final - optimised: 6.664197575327741
Final - non-optimised: 7.353876372743493

Process finished with exit code 0
```